# Browser auto scrolls to form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have designed a one-page homepage with lots of content, in which a contact form is implemented at the bottom (see http://neu.logopaedie-scheithauer.de/). Upon opening the page for the first time, most browsers (IE, FF, Safari) scroll down to the first field of the contact form, possibly due to an auto focus.

This undesired behaviour leads to a bad user experience, as the user expects to read the page from top to bottom. However, I can't figure out, how to stop it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the `runonload` function, and just removing the code, will fix the issue. Let us know if it has fixed. Just remove this code from the file `contactform.js`:

```
runOnLoad(function(){
    $("input#name").select().focus();
});
```